# How to access data on server side from AJAX post request

Tags: node.js, ajax

I have tried reading a lot of posts on this but none have really helped me. I don't get how to access the data I am sending from a post request. For context, I have a .ejs html file where I am making an asynchronous post request to the server. This is the code for that:

```
                $("#commentButton" + thisPostId).click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/comment",
                        data: {
                            comment: $("#commentInput" + thisPostId).val(),
                            postId: $("#postIdInput" + thisPostId).val()
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.success) {
                                let asyncComment = "<p>whatsupbro</p>";
                                $("#li" + thisPostId).append(asyncComment);
                            } else {
                                // ADD BETTER ERROR IMPL
                                alert('error');
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

On the server side, I want to retrieve the arguments in "data". This is what I have so far. I have tried so many things, like doing req.data.comment, req.comment, etc. Below is the start of my node.js function that is supposed to get the request and do some stuff with it. What matters is I want the comment in commentInfo and postId in commentInfo to be what I am sending in the post request as "comment" and "postId". I really am just not sure how to access this data (req.body.mycomment doesn't work either).

```
var createComment = function(req, res) {
    var commentInfo = {
        comment: req.body.myComment,
        username: req.session.username,
        commentId: new Date().getTime(),
        postId: req.body.postId
    };
    console.log(req['comment']);
```

Thanks for the help. If there is anything else I should add let me know.

Comment: what is the output you are getting when running - console.log(req.body)

Comment: Are you using Express on the server?  If so, you need the appropriate middleware for whatever content-type you're sending so the incoming data stream will be read and parsed into `req.body`.  Without that, the data would still be sitting in the stream waiting to be read and parsed and `req.body` would be an empty object.

Comment: Let me check the req.body, I am running express that is how I am doing the routing.

Comment: req.body is right now empty when I do console.log... I'm not sure what you mean @jfriend00 , how do I do this middleware?

Comment: What content-type are you sending with your POST and are you using Express on your server?

Comment: This helped i actually got it :D

Answer (score 0):

You need appropriate middleware to actually read the body of the POST request and to then parse it and place the contents into `req.body`.

Assuming you are using Express, then you need one of these placed before the route that receives the POST:

```
app.use(express.json());           // for application/json content-type
app.use(express.urlencoded());     // for application/x-www-form-urlencoded content-type
```

Comment: @dmzach - Since it looks like you may be new here, if this helped you find your answer, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.